# Understand scores from bestScores function in DMwR package

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I'm going through the code in Chapter 2 of Luis Torgo's Data Mining with R textbook, also found here:
http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~ltorgo/DataMiningWithR/code2.html.

I would like to understand exactly what the scores are in the bestScores function output.  I think that they are the NMSE (normalized mean squared error), but I was under the impression that normalization means that these scores are between 0 and 1.  Ostensibly, the lower the score the better, but I would like to make sure.  Please note that the experimentalComparison function takes about 1-2 minutes to run.

```
if (require(rpart)==F) install.packages("rpart"); require(rpart)
if (require(DMwR)==F) install.packages("DMwR"); require(DMwR)

data(algae)
algae <- algae[-manyNAs(algae), ]
clean.algae <- knnImputation(algae, k = 10)

lm.a1 <- lm(a1 ~ .,data=clean.algae[,1:12])
rt.a1 <- rpart(a1 ~ .,data=algae[,1:12])

final.lm <- step(lm.a1)

lm.predictions.a1 <- predict(final.lm,clean.algae)
rt.predictions.a1 <- predict(rt.a1,algae)

cv.rpart <- function(form,train,test,...) {
  m <- rpartXse(form,train,...)
  p <- predict(m,test)
  mse <- mean((p-resp(form,test))^2)
  c(nmse=mse/mean((mean(resp(form,train))-resp(form,test))^2))
}
cv.lm <- function(form,train,test,...) {
  m <- lm(form,train,...)
  p <- predict(m,test)
  p <- ifelse(p < 0,0,p)
  mse <- mean((p-resp(form,test))^2)
  c(nmse=mse/mean((mean(resp(form,train))-resp(form,test))^2))
}

res <- experimentalComparison(
  c(dataset(a1 ~ .,clean.algae[,1:12],'a1')),
  c(variants('cv.lm'), 
    # 3 tree models each with a different 
    # complexity
    variants('cv.rpart',se=c(0,0.5,1))),
  # 3 times 10-fold cross-validation
  # 1234 is seed 
  cvSettings(3,10,1234))

getVariant('cv.rpart.v1',res)

DSs <- sapply(names(clean.algae)[12:18],
              function(x,names.attrs) { 
                f <- as.formula(paste(x,"~ ."))
                # dataset is a class of objects that represent all necessary
                # information on a predictive task
                # dataset(formula, data, name)
                dataset(f,clean.algae[,c(names.attrs,x)],x) 
              },
              names(clean.algae)[1:11])

res.all <- experimentalComparison(
  DSs,
  c(variants('cv.lm'),
    variants('cv.rpart',se=c(0,0.5,1))
  ),
  cvSettings(5,10,1234))

bestScores(res.all)
```

Here is the output:

```
> bestScores(res.all)
$a1
          system   score
nmse cv.rpart.v1 0.64231

$a2
          system score
nmse cv.rpart.v3     1

$a3
          system score
nmse cv.rpart.v2     1

$a4
          system score
nmse cv.rpart.v2     1

$a5
       system     score
nmse cv.lm.v1 0.9316803

$a6
       system     score
nmse cv.lm.v1 0.9359697

$a7
          system    score
nmse cv.rpart.v3 1.029505
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://rem.jrc.ec.europa.eu/RemWeb/atmes2/20b.htm) website, NMSE can be greater than 1.  The smaller the number the better the model performs in space and time.

Comment: Torgo's book also says that measure can be greater than 1 (on the page right after it is defined.). I do think calling this "normalized" is questionable.